# How to get the max distance between two airplanes

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I hope that someone can help me with the problem i have.

I have 3 Airplanes `A`, `B`, `C` The Time intervals are: `A[0..12]`, `B[7..18]`, `C[11..23]`. Now i need to find the optimal time for every Airplane to land one after another

The result should be this:

```
?- air_traffic_control(A,B,C).
A = 0,
B = 11,
C = 22.
```

The only thing I wrote for now is

```
air_traffic_control(A,B,C) :-
    A in 0..12,
    B in 7..18,
    C in 11..23,
    label([A,B,C]).
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by max landing distance.

Comment: I mean the optimal time to every Airplane to land.

Comment: It shouldn't be so hard, i think i just need maybe a math equation....to calculate that time... but maybe i am overthinking it a little.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you mean. What are the intervals? What would be the expected result here?

Comment: The intervals are time intervals...So the expected result is to find the optimal time for every single Airplane to land one after another. So first A then B then C.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can't you just explain what the result is supposed to be in your example?

Comment: I will add it to my question.

Comment: @Fatalize what @twiitedhat wants here is to maximize the time between the three landings. The numbers are acting as clock times. A good solution is `A=0, B=11, C=22` because it staggers the times better than (say) `A=0, B=7` because it gives A 4 minutes less time to clear the runway.

Comment: @DanielLyons If you are sure about this interpretation of the question you might want to edit it. It wasn't answered because it wasn't clear from looking at it what is expected (I have also flagged it as "unclear what you are asking").

Comment: maximize product of distances between consecutive planes?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have defined what you mean by distance and constrained a variable `Distance` accordingly, SWI-Prolog allows you to maximize it using `labeling([max(Distance)], [Distance])`.

**Edit:** After you clarified how you want to model this, it's easy to do: The `=<` relation is written `#=<` in CLPFD, and conjunction ("and") is just written using the comma `,` as usual in Prolog. So you can write your constraints like this:

```
flights_distance([A, B, C], MinDistance) :-
    A in 0..12,
    B in 7..18,
    C in 11..23,
    MinDistance #> 0,
    MinDistance #=< B - A,
    MinDistance #=< C - B.
```

Note that this predicate contains constraints but no calls to `labeling`. It is a so-called *core relation* that contains a model but keeps it separate from the search. This is considered [good practice](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-search).

The core relation and the search can then be combined in another predicate:

```
flights_scheduled(Flights) :-
    flights_distance(Flights, MinDistance),
    labeling([max(MinDistance)], [MinDistance|Flights]).
```

In SWI-Prolog, this will evaluate all solutions of the model, with solutions with maximal distance first:

```
?- flights_scheduled(Flights).
Flights = [0, 11, 22] ;
Flights = [0, 11, 23] ;
Flights = [0, 12, 23] ;
Flights = [1, 12, 23] ;
Flights = [0, 10, 20] ;
Flights = [0, 10, 21] ;
Flights = [0, 10, 22] ;
Flights = [0, 10, 23] ;
Flights = [0, 11, 21] ;
Flights = [0, 11, 22] .
```

If you only want the first solution, you can wrap the whole thing in `once(...)` or put a cut after the call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the minimal distance D between those 3  would be:

```
D =< ((B-A) and D) =< C-B.
```

or am i wrong?
If not, how can i write this in prolog?

Comment: OK, I updated my answer accordingly. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks alot this helped me out. Any ideas how i can label it without defining a new predicate?. So if i just want flights_distance(A,B,C) and then the returns?

Comment: If you want that, you can just put all the code into one predicate.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you just set D to be #= to both of these distances (A,B) and (B,C), and then maximize D. hth